# Angularjs sce injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sce injection not working in angularjs 1.5.8.
Trying this in controller:

```
myWg.controller('MainCtrl', mainCtrl);
mainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http','$q','$rootScope','$sce'];
function mainCtrl($scope,$http,$q,$rootScope, $sce){
    ...
    $sce.trustAsHtml(p.value);
    ...
```

And getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'trustAsHtml' of undefined

Is it possible there is injection order issue here?
$http and $q is working fine, but depends on injection order might be also undefined.

thank you for any help.

-solved-
this constuction worked, but not clear why '$inject variant' didn't work

```
myWg.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$q','$rootScope','$sce',
function($scope,$http,$q,$rootScope, $sce){
```

Comment: did you include [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) in your module dependencies?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman no, i didn't

Comment: @АндрейА can you share the html as well as controller code properly ?

Comment: it is used as attribute ng-bind-html="value" in html, but the error is earlier with injection. so in this case the issue was injecton method as i wrote in update.